# How to make R legend with 2 columns?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to make a legend on my graph, which is generated by `plot()` function. The original `legend()` function will generate a list which has only 1 column. How can I make a legend which has 2 columns?

[image: Wanted legend]

Comment: `ncol = 2` in `legend` ?

Comment: But I need only 1 text label per row

Comment: @FelixChan One Text label per row

Comment: Please include a reproducible example and a clearer description of how the desired legend is supposed to look.

Comment: @BenBarnes The legend actually looks like the image I draw above. There are 2 different lines but the are using the same label. You can consider the solid line is actually result and the dotted line is the expected result, but they are representing the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could not find a way to do that within a single call to `legend` for standard plots.

Here's an option, drawing two separate legends: one with lines and points, one with labels. `x.intersp` can be used to tweak distance between labels and lines.

```
plot(cumsum(runif(n = 100)))

# draw legend with lines and point but without labels and box. x.intersp controls horizontal distance between lines
L = legend(x = 'bottom', legend = rep(NA,4), col=1:2, lty=c(1,1,2,2), ncol=2, bty='n', x.intersp=0.5, pch=c(1,2,1,2), inset=0.02)

# use position data of previous legend to draw legend with invisble lines and points but with labels and box. x.intersp controls distance between lines and labels
legend(x = L$rect$left, y = L$rect$top, legend = c('Group A', 'Group B'), col=rep(NA,2), lty=c(1,1), ncol=1, x.intersp = 3, bg = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
library(lattice)

myPCH <- 15:17
Data  <- rnorm(50)
Index <- seq(length(Data))

xyplot(Data ~ Index, 
       pch = myPCH, col=1:2,
       key = list(space = "right", adj=1,
                  text = list(c("a", "b", "c"), cex=1.5),
                  points = list(pch = myPCH),
                  points = list(pch = myPCH,col=2)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a 2x2 lines + 2x1 string.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Victorp answered this in the comments of the original post. The ncol argument in the legend function works for me:

```
legend(locator(1), legend=c("name1","name2", "name3", "name4"), lty=2, col=c("black", "blue", "dark green", "orange"), ncol=2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W52o.png)