# How can I justify multiple parts of legend in R?

Tags: r, legend, justify

I want to left-justify one part of the legend and right-justify the rest.

Here's the code:

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", axes=F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
legend(2,8,legend = c(paste("Muito baixo:", start), paste("Baixo:", middle[1]), paste("Médio:", middle[2]), paste("Alto:", middle[3]), paste("Muito alto:", end)), fill = RdYlGn, bty = "n", cex = 1.4)
```

Now my legend looks like this:

[image: NOW]

and I want something like this:

[image: NEW]

Comment: I don't know a way in base graphics to support this; effectively you're asking for multiple columns, since the font is variable-width and there is not "expanding whitespace" concept. I think you're going to need to go the route of two legends, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692288/3358272

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32031579/1552004):

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", axes=F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
foo <- legend(2,8,legend = c("Muito baixo:","Baixo:","Médio:","Alto:","Muito alto:"), bty = "n", cex = 1.4)
text(0.5 + foo$rect$left + foo$rect$w, foo$text$y, c("<58", "58-68", "68-74", "74-84", ">84"), cex = 1.4, pos = 2)
```

The `0.5` is a buffer that will need to be adjusted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Lyngbakr's:

```
leg <- round(aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data=mtcars, FUN=range))
leg$disp <- apply(leg$disp, 1, paste, collapse="-")
leg$txt <- c("Four Cylinders", "Six", "Eight")
plot(disp~mpg, col=cyl, data=mtcars, pch=16)
l <- legend("topright", title="Cyl ~ Disp",
            legend = leg$txt, pch = 16, col = leg$cyl,
            text.width = max(strwidth(paste(leg$txt, "   ", leg$disp))),
            xjust = 1, yjust = 1)
text(l$rect$left + l$rect$w, l$text$y - 0.2*strheight("W"),
     leg$disp, pos=2)
```

[image: sample plot from mtcars]

Notes:

- The use of `"   "` within `strwidth` was to provide a little buffer, can be changed to suit taste;
- The right-column text was a little offset vertically from the text of the actual legend, so I added a buffer. Since this is dependent on the font size and the units of the y-axis, I used a multiple of `strheight`, play with it with your own data.

Heavily influenced by [How to make labels in the legend align right in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031530/how-to-make-labels-in-the-legend-align-right-in-r)